# How to run my code in the right path with WSL? I have edit settings.json already

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I setup WSL Ubuntu but I can't run my code in the right path with WSL .
How to run my code in the right path with WSL ?

This is my settings.json

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe"
"code-runner.executorMap":
{ 
"c": "cd $(wslpath $dir) & gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt & ./$fileNameWithoutExt"
"cpp": "g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt -std=c++11 & ./$fileNameWithoutExt"}\
"python": "python3 -u ./$fileName"
}
```

When I run my code with "ctrl+alt+N"
The output became:

```
jamesqian@J:/mnt/c/Users/Jamesqian/Desktop/tmp$ cd $(wslpath "c:\Users\Jamesqian\Desktop\tmp\") & gcc test.c -o test & ./test
```

wslpath is [here](https://github.com/laurent22/wslpath)